# What is the error um:loader_init_failure_status_dll_not_found_c0000135_asckc!nnknown?

Tags: c++, windbg

I got the error when I tried to analyze my Dump Crash File using WinDbg. I corrected my source path and symbol path when I analyzed this issue. I don't know what is the error and why this error happens.

```
ExceptionAddress: 773e774d (ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x00059ba1)
       ExceptionCode: c0000135
      ExceptionFlags: 00000001
    NumberParameters: 0

    PROCESS_NAME:  asckc.exe 
    EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000135 - The program can't start because %hs is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

    NTGLOBALFLAG:  0
    BUGCHECK_STR:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND
    DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND

    STACK_TEXT:  
    00000000 00000000 asckc.exe!Unknown+0x0                      

    STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

    BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND_asckc.exe!Unknown

    PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND_asckc.exe!Unknown

    FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND

    FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  c0000135


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  LOADER_INIT_FAILURE_STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND_c0000135_asckc.exe!Unknown

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:loader_init_failure_status_dll_not_found_c0000135_asckc.exe!unknown
```

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that there is a DLL that your program (or a DLL loaded by your program) needs to run, but Windows is unable to load it.  This can be because something isn't installed right, or you haven't copied all of the DLLs your program needs into the folder you are running from.  The error isn't listing the problem DLL so I can't help you any more than that.

You can look for a program called [DEPENDS (by Microsoft)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/06/25/analyze-application-failures-the-easier-way-with-dependency-walker.aspx) that can help track down these sorts of problems.